# configure not adding line-continuation characters to makefile

Tags: compiling, make, configure

This is, perhaps, a bit of a bizarre one but I don't even know where to *start* looking so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

I've just done a fresh install of my distribution, which included moving to the next release (yup, it's Ubuntu) and so am rebuilding/installing a load of stuff that I usually have in addition to whatever the distribution provides (latest versions and so forth).  Anyway, I was merrily doing so with one (a slightly customised version of emacs) when I found `make` complaining a lot.  Looking at the makefile(s), I found that the configure script hadn't put any "continuation line" characters in.

The configure script is rather long (this is emacs, after all) and just searching for `\` is rather pointless!  So does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

(As I said, it's a fresh install so maybe it's just some package that I forgot to install.  But it's a bit bizarre.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess that may or may not be right.

- Hypothesis: You've already configured and built Emacs in that directory before the upgrade.
- Hypothesis: Your shell (`/bin/sh`) changed during the upgrade.
- Hypothesis: Emacs caches some data about the shell.

If these hypotheses are true, the configure script may have cached information about your shell's handling of backslashes. There are incompatibilities between shells in that respect, in particular with the `echo` built-in, so if the cache contains outdated information, the output could be missing backslashes or have doubled backslashes.

Run `make distclean` to wipe the cache and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I _can't_ run `make distclean` due to the aforementioned problem with the makefile!  So I wiped the directory and reloaded it (I'm not familiar enough with the DVCS used to revert to pristine) but I still get the same problem.  I'm now trying under bash (I use zsh normally) ... nope, same problem.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm afraid you're going to have to link to the precise source you're trying to compile (a tag in the bazaar repository? With custom patches?).

Comment: @Gilles: I've just tried a version that I know used to work (as it's the one I compiled before I updated my machine) so I strongly suspect that there's a problem on my system.  I think that what I need to do is find a small example to test of a configure script (do you happen to know any?).  If you _really_ want to know what I'm trying to compile, it's the _tiling_ version of emacs available here: http://arch.savannah.gnu.org/archives/emacs/emacs/emacs--tiling/emacs--tiling--0/ (I made some notes on what to do: http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/Unix/Transparent_Emacs.html )

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Does running the configure script as `bash ./configure` or `ksh ./configure` make a difference? Try running `bash -x ./configure` or `ksh -x configure` to see a trace of what the shell is doing. Add the trace to your question if you need help understanding it.

Comment: @Gilles: Running under bash didn't make a difference.  I'll try with the `-x` switches tomorrow (I just tried and the output was rather long, and it's rather late here, so I'll take another look tomorrow).  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks again for the help.  In the end, I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Debian (I had other annoyances) and it all just worked again.